# How can I remove rows of data using a list of files as the input?

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple files (`20+`) containing millions of lines of data, which all start with a file name/path.  I've generated a list of duplicate files, which I need to remove from the data.

I'm trying to learn more about Pandas with Python and cannot figure out how to use the duplicate file list as input.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Data.csv')
df.columns = ['ColA','ColB']
```

I need to figure out how to pull in a file list `'Duplicates.txt'` and use that list to remove rows where `ColA` is the file list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Data.csv')
df.columns = ['ColA','ColB']
dups = pd.read_csv('Duplicates.txt')

df_final = df.loc[df.ColA.isin(dups.columnname),:]
```

Comment: import pandas as pd  
df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv', low_memory=False)  
#(Needed to fix the DtypeWarning)  
df.columns = ['ColA','ColB','ColC','ColD','ColE','ColF','ColG','ColH',]  
dups = pd.read_csv('Duplicates_To_Delete.csv')  
df_final = df.loc[df.ColA.isin(dups.DupFiles),:]  
df_final.to_csv('Data_NoDupes.csv')  
  
  
Thank you. However, this outputs just the duplicate lines of data.  
  
I'm going to see if I can figure out how to output the data without the duplicates.

Comment: Use "not" `~` like this: `df_final = df.loc[~df.ColA.isin(dups.columnname),:]`